# Sunspot search doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to make an search option in my site, but it won't show results after an search query.
I have followed this tutorial: http://collectiveidea.com/blog/archives/2011/03/08/full-text-searching-with-solr-and-sunspot/

My routes.rb:

```
    resources :users do
      collection do
        get :search
      end    
      member do
        get :following, :followers      
      end
    end

My index.html.erb

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>

   <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', user %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_path(user) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
              </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
    <br />

<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_path %>

My model user.rb

searchable do
  text :name
end    

And my user controller

def index
  @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
end

   def search
    @users = User.search do
      keywords params[:query]
    end.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "index" }
    end
   end
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have any users? Did you run `rake sunspot:reindex` after adding users?

Comment: Thankyou!! So i have everytime to run this command after adding new users?

Comment: No, you won't have to run it every time. Each new user will be indexed automatically. You needed to reindex though for all the users that you already had before adding sunspot.